# If a system $Ax = b$ has unique solution $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, why is $x$ also the unique solution in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Trying to prove this but running into roadblocks; why do we know that since it is unique in the reals, that it is also a unique solution in the complex numbers?

Comment: Nowhere in the process of Gaussian elimination do you actually use the fact that you are manipulating real numbers (give all the entries of your matrix and right hand side letter names and you'll see that all your calculations can be written in terms of basic operations that are valid for any field, not just the reals). Hence when you do Gaussian elimination to show that there is a unique real solution, you are actually showing that there is a unique solution in any larger field, and that that solution happens to be real is a coincidence that you observe when you replace letters by numbers.

Comment: You do not say that $A$ has real entries, right?

Comment: You should add that $A$ has real entries.

Answer (score 4):

Say $A z = A (u+iv) = A u + i A v = b$. We conclude $Au = b$ and $A v = 0$. Now, necessarily $v = 0$,  otherwise we have at least two solutions $x$ and $x+v$. Also we must have $u=x$, since $u$ is a solution from above. We get $z = u + i v= x + i 0 = x$.

$\bf{Added:}$ We use that the matrix $A$ has real entries. Here is a counterexample with $A \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$.

The system
$$\left (\begin{matrix}
    1 & i \\
    i & -1 
    \end{matrix}\right) \cdot \left (\begin{matrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 
    \end{matrix}\right)= \left (\begin{matrix}
    0 \\
    0 
    \end{matrix}\right) $$
has a unique real solution $x=0$, but infinitely many complex solution $t\cdot (1,i)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first assume $b=0$. In this case, the unique solution is the trivial solution $x=0$. By the invertible matrix theorem, $A$ is invertible in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ so there exists an inverse $A^{-1} \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) \subset M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Therefore we have an inverse in the real numbers. Hope this helps and you can perhaps generalize this sort of argument.

Comment: The best solution, doesn't need to assume that $A$ has real entries like some of the other answers.